# knockout.js-ko not found

Tags: knockout.js

this is my js file:

```
function AppViewModel() 
{
    this.firstName = ko.observable("Bert");
    this.lastName = ko.observable("Bertington");
}
ko.applyBindings(AppViewModel());
```

this is my html file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='ko.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='knockout-2.1.0.debug.js'></script>

</head>
<body>
    <p>First name: <strong data-bind="text: firstName"></strong></p>
    <p>Last name: <strong data-bind="text: lastName"></strong></p>

    <p>First name: <input data-bind="value: firstName" /></p>
    <p>Last name: <input data-bind="value: lastName" /></p>
</body>
</html>
```

**Uncaught ReferenceError: ko is not defined**.

Can someone help me with this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8):

Try reversing the order of your JavaScript files -

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='knockout-2.1.0.debug.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='ko.js'></script>
```

I suspect that the `ko.js` file is trying to access the `ko` object before it's been defined in the main 'knockout' js file.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to place my ko scripts into order as above and also execute any ko.xyz code after the document has loaded with the JQuery (or equivalent) document ready function. e.g.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
            var model = new ReviewersViewModel();
            ko.applyBindings(model);

            $('.datetimepicker_mask').datetimepicker({
                mask: '9999/19/39 29:59'
            });

            ko.bindingHandlers.datetimepicker = {
                init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
                    //initialize datepicker with some optional options
                    var options = allBindingsAccessor().datetimepickerOptions || {};
                    $(element).datetimepicker(options);

                    //handle the field changing
                    ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function () {
                        var observable = valueAccessor();
                        try {
                            observable($(element).datetimepicker("getDate"));//****
                        }
                        catch (ex) { }
                    });

                    //handle disposal (if KO removes by the template binding)
                    ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
                        $(element).datetimepicker("destroy");
                    });

                },
                update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
                    var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
                        current = $(element).datetimepicker("getDate");

                    if (value - current !== 0) {
                        $(element).datetimepicker("setDate", value);
                    }
                }
            };
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the script, Which is Knockout js library it is contain knockout predefined methods.

Comment: <script src="http://knockoutjs.com/downloads/knockout-3.0.0.debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>